# Between 2 Androids and to other OS mobiles

Tags: android, smartphone, vnc-viewer

The `PhoneMyPC` tool in Android provides a remote desktop connection to the PC. 
But now I am wondering whether `Android` based mobiles support the `VNC` protocol/softwares for a connection between 2 Android mobiles?

And furthermore do Android based mobiles support `RDP` or are there other tools to connect to other mobile OS's like `windows`, `symbian` etc ?

Thanks in advance,
Karthik Balaguru

Answer (score 0):

Not really a programming question, are you trying to develop a solution?

Yes, there are applications in the market at this time that support VNC, and RDP protocols.

Comment: Can you lemme know few applications that use VNC/RDP protocol between 2 mobiles. I searched the internet, but did not find a application that is used between 2 mobiles/smartphones. Any ideas/links ?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, as far as I know there are no program's that do this between mobiles, but VNC/RDP is for controlling desktop computers, I'm not sure what the reason would be to control a mobile phone in this manner.